# Need help setting up a jQuery plugin "SpriteSpin"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the plugin page:
http://spritespin.ginie.eu/howto.html

Here is my site:
http://chronox.netai.net/

Scroll down to the very bottom to see the issue.

I want that plugin inside the last section (the slider with arrows and the '360*'.

I've followed the instructions. But obviously it's not showing up. Can someone take a look at the code and see if it's right?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(".threesixty-gold").spritespin({
  // path to the source images.
  source: [
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0000.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0001.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0002.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0003.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0004.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0005.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0006.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0007.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0008.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0009.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0010.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0011.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0012.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0012.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0013.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0014.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0015.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0016.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0017.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0018.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0019.jpg",
  "assets/img/threesixty/gold/gold0020.jpg",



  ],
  width   : 1900,  // width in pixels of the window/frame
  height  : 930,  // height in pixels of the window/frame
});

</script>
```

Comment: where did you insert sprite js? you only have jquery in your code

Answer (score 2):

<del>you need to put your code in `$( document ).ready(function() {});`</del>
**updated**
you are missing `spritespin.js` reference.
`<script src='spritespin.js' type='text/javascrip' />`

Comment: or $(function(){...}); which is a shorter way of doing the same thing

Comment: i can't see any spritespin.js in the code, based on your suggestion; you can. Just where the hell is that thing man? I looked everywhere. There are only four js inserts, and none of them is spritespin

Comment: and why does she need to run it in document ready? Spritespin js is running after the dom is loaded

Comment: @ozil Hey thanks! Duh! However it's still not working for some reason.

Comment: @Celine you just need to add `spritespin.js`. no need to include your code in $( document ).ready(function() {}) as per the documentation says

Comment: @ozil okay thanks, I have done so, but still not working

<script src='assets/js/spritespin.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

Comment: @Celine you haven't included the right file `use the spritespin.js from the dist directory, not the one from src directory. If you use the one from src directory, you have to reference all the other scripts too, to make it work.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include sprite js in your html. You may insert it right after jquery.

```
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js' type='text/javascript' />
<script src='spritespin.js' type='text/javascrip' />
```